# Why did Miss Monochrome become a bear?

Tags: japanese-language, miss-monochrome

In Episode 4 of Season 2 of Miss Monochrome, Miss Monochrome wants to have an action figure made as merchandise for her concert tour. Her manager tells her it might be difficult, so she decides to become an action figure based on her own merits.

For some reason, this leads her to become a bear, as terrifyingly recounted in the following scene.

[image]
[image]
[image]

There seems to be some kind of silly pun in play here, but I couldn't make out what it was. What contortion of the Japanese language led Miss Monochrome to think dressing up as a bear would make her an action figure?

Comment: Since her name is Monochrome, I was thinking of Monokuma, a character from Danganronpa, which then explain why she became a bear (kuma is Japanese for bear), but no idea what does that have to do with action figure.

Comment: @SakuraiTomoko It was some kind of pun on the words *figyua* (figure) and what sounded like *higuma*, which I assume comes from *kuma* (bear). I was hoping someone could explain it.

Comment: Also, we needed more Miss Monochrome questions to help her on her way to becoming an idol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Torisuda's clue, Figuma is a reference to [Figma](http://www.figma.jp), a company that sells action figures. Higuma sounds similar to Figma and it means Sun Bear (hi/日 = sun, kuma/熊 = bear). Thus, Miss Monochrome turned into a sun bear.

[image: sun bears are brown]

Comment: I don't think ヒ means 日{ひ} 'sun' here.  I think ヒグマ was originally シクマ, which is said to come from reading 羆 as 四{し} over 熊{くま} (although of course 罒 really indicates a net).

Comment: @snailboat Can you explain what the joke would be if you're right? Maybe in an answer? :)